# google app script- How to Check the folder is exist

Tags: javascript

I am using google app script, I want to check the /root/Received Files/folderName whether it is exist or not. If not exist then I want to create it.
But it always show an error when

```
Subfolders.hasNext()
```

How could I fix my code?

```javascript
function getFolders(folderName)
{      
  var Subfolder;var Subfolders
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();     
 while (folders.hasNext()) {
   var folder = folders.next();
   if('Received Files' == folder.getName()) {         
     Subfolders=folder;
     while(Subfolders.hasNext()) ==> ERR
     {
        Subfolder=Subfolders.next();
        if(folderName == Subfolder.getName()) 
        {
          return Subfolder
        }
     }
   }
 }
  Subfolder=Subfolders.createFolder(folderName);
  return Subfolder;
}
```

Comment: When asking for help debugging something, you're required to provide the error message as part of the question.  Please try to do that next time.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I will do that next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do:

```
Subfolders = folder.getFolders();
```

Not

```
Subfolders = folder;
```